# How can I build a responsive tiled photo gallery using JS?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, frontend

So, I'm trying to get started conceptualizing a project for a friend of mine and I've run into a sort of problem right away.

They're wanting to do a photography website, which isn't a big deal, but I'm not sure how to go about replicating the functionality they're seeking for their front page.

This link is an example they gave me.  They're looking to have a sort of "tile" setup of images from a gallery/folder that cleanly line up along the edges of the page (if possible) and are also responsive, so when you reach certain breakpoints, the images obviously shift to have less in each row, but still keep the same clean look.

http://www.amishakpatel.com

I figure it's probably possible to do this with various client-side JS libraries, but I'm out of practice and didn't know where to turn.

Any suggestions would be fantastic, I get the feeling that this specific part of this project is going to be more complex that I originally thought, and I'm not SUPER experienced in the art of writing responsive layouts, but I wanted to give this a shot and get better at it.

My original plan was to develop this thing as a WP website/theme, but now I'm almost wondering if due to the nature of the project that I should maybe just use WP for the backend and content management, then do the front-end separately using front-end that I'm a bit more comfortable with (React) as it's looking like the whole project will be heavy in JS anyway to do the stuff they're wanting to eventually do.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-masonry-layouts.html

Comment: masonry layouts would be the right direction to google :-)  You could also try to get a flex flow layout going and calculate the size of the images on page resize....

Comment: Plus the height of the images seem to be all similar, making it easier for the wrapping ...

Answer (score 0):

After reading the advice given by the few folks who commented, I did some digging with Mosaic/Masonry layouts, and found this:

https://www.imagely.com/wordpress-gallery-plugin/

I'm gonna give this a shot, which lets me stick with WP for a platform for ease of use, keeping the whole project simple.

Thanks a lot, folks!  I figured there was PROBABLY a word for what I was looking for in terms of layout, but didn't know what to Google.  :P

Comment: I did something similar to this using a npm package. For more details and examples you can refer this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-photo-gallery